# Using output of a function that is a command in a Tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI for my project. I want to use the output list from a function being called as command in my Tkinter button to another functions. I've already seen similar questions regarding this concern, but I haven't encountered returning a List yet.

Here is the sample of my code

```
# <imports and window root here>

coordList = []
coordList1 = []

def match(s):
    for i in range(s):
        coor_label = Label(root, text=f"Coordinate {i + 1}: ").grid(column=0, row=i, sticky="w")
        coor_entry = Entry(root, bd=2)
        coor_entry.grid(column=1, row=i, sticky="w")
        coordList.append(coor_entry)

def wer():
    for i in coordList:
        j = i.get()
        coordList1.append(j)
    return coordList1

click = Button(root, text="Click", command=lambda: match(3))
click.grid(row=0, column=2)  # The code is working fine up to this line

run = Button(root, text="Run", command=lambda: wer())
run.grid(row=1, column=2) # Even if I do print(coordList1) in wer(), it's not working

# <Upon clicking 'run' button, I want to use the coordList1 for another functions>

*root.mainloop()
```

Solutions should not include OOP stuff. Also, can I automate the input of a number 's' in match(s)?

Suppose I want to add a function that would compute for the difference of coordinates and will be stored in coordList2, ie, Coordinate 2 - Coordinate 1, Coordinate 3 - Coordinate 2, etc. I introduced a new function, asd(). See some sample code below:

```
# <imports and window root here>

coordList = []
coordList1 = []

def match(s):
    for i in range(s):
        coor_label = Label(root, text=f"Coordinate {i + 1}: ").grid(column=0, row=i, sticky="w")
        coor_entry = Entry(root, bd=2)
        coor_entry.grid(column=1, row=i, sticky="w")
        coordList.append(coor_entry)

def wer():
    for i in coordList:
        j = i.get()
        coordList1.append(j)
    return coordList1

def asd():
    for i in coordList1:
        h = i - 1
        if h >= 0:
             j = i.get() - h.get()
             coordList2.append(j)
        else:
             pass

click = Button(root, text="Click", command=lambda: match(3))
click.grid(row=0, column=2)  # The code is working fine up to this line

run = Button(root, text="Run", command=lambda: asd())
run.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

If I print coordList2, the console only shows `[]`. What should I modify in the code to work as I intend to?

Comment: you can already use it in other functions (also `return coordList1` is not necessary, it doesn't do anything really)

Comment: As `coordList1` is a global list, you can access it in any functions of current scope/module.

Comment: @acw1668 if I try to use/print coordList1 after clicking the Run button, but the console only prints []. I edited my question, maybe I was able to express what I intend to accomplish now

Comment: @Matiiss I edited my question, when I set asd() function as command in run button, it's only printing []

Comment: Did you run `match()` by clicking *"Click"* button before clicking *"Run"* button?  I have no issue if I click the two buttons in that order.  Just notice that your updated code has never execute `wer()` so `coordList1` has never been updated.

Comment: Your updated code should fail because `coordList2` inside `asd()` is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

i think it well work

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

coordList = []
coordList1 = []

def match(s):
    
    def wer():
        for i in coordList:
            j = i.get()
            coordList1.append(j)
        print(coordList1)
    for i in range(s):
        coor_label = Label(root, text=f"Coordinate {i + 1}: ").grid(column=0, row=i, sticky="w")
        coor_entry = Entry(root, bd=2)
        coor_entry.grid(column=1, row=i, sticky="w")
        coordList.append(coor_entry)
        
    run = Button(root, text="Run", command=lambda: wer())
    run.grid(row=1, column=2)

    def wer():
        for i in coordList:
            j = i.get()
            coordList1.append(j)
        print(coordList1)

click = Button(root, text="Click", command=lambda: match(8))
click.grid(row=0, column=2)  #code is working fine up to this line
 #even if I do print(coordList1) in wer(), it's not working

# Upon clicking 'run' button, I want to use the coordList1 for another functions**

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Abdul it worked. I edited my question to imply what I really wanted to achieve in the sample code given that a new function is to be solved from coordList1 result.